# take data from an html code

Tags: php, bash

I need to store some information from an html with bash or php

Part of the code in htm is

```
</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="datastation">
<div class="bit-66">
<div id="resum-diari" style="position:relative">
<h5>Daily Summary
</h5>
<div class="table">
<table summary="Weather Data today">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Temperature max</th>
<td>

10.5 °C



</td>
<tr>
<th>Temperature min</th>
<td>  


0.1 °C



</td>
<tr>
<th>Precipitation</th>
<td colspan="2">


0.8 mm



</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#nameStation').html('Oslo');
$('#dataToday').html('03.12.2014');
</script>
</div>
</div>
<h4>Oslo</h4>
<table summary="Current Weather">
<tr>
<th>City</th>
<td>Oslo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Country</th>
<td>Norway</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Height</th>
<td>15 m</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And I need to store in a csv, the next data

```
City, Temperature max, Temperature min, Precipitation
Oslo, 10.5,0.1,0.8
```

Can you help me?

I have tried with this code, but something in this case doesn't run

```
awk -F'<|>' -v OFS="," 'NF>3{if (r) {r=r OFS $3} else r=$3} /tr/ {print r; r=""}' $dir/Oslo.htm
```

Comment: try   PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Comment: I would have recommended [`xmllint`](http://man.cx/xmllint)... but many a times, `html` presented by websites is not proper `xml` (e.g. unclosed img or br tags...) For `xhtml` data, however, `xmllint` would work just as `xml`..

Comment: This is a job suited to an HTML parser, not a tool like awk. You need to tidy up the HTML in your question to make the structure clear - at the moment it's not at all obvious why the `<h4>` further down the page has anything to do with the data above.

Comment: It is solved! I have used Grep -A 3 'Temperature max' data.htm > data.txt and then I use awk, tmax=`awk 'NR == 4' tmax.txt....

Answer (score 0):

It is solved! I have used Grep -A 3 'Temperature max' data.htm > data.txt and then I use awk, tmax=`awk 'NR == 4' tmax.txt.... –  Enric Agud Pique